# Python Graph Changes

Tags: python, dictionary, graph, copy

I have a Graph like this:

```
{'0': {'4': 1},
'1': {},
 '2': {'3': 1, '4': 1},
 '3': {'2': 1},
 '4': {'0': 1, '2': 1}}
```

and I want to make some changes to it by removing a specific edge, but I also want to retain the original graph. So i use

```
temp=copy.copy(graph)
```

to make a copy out of it. And then I run the function (on the new copy) which removes the specific edge that I want,( for example edge three which in this case is between node 2 and node 3 ) but What i get is that change also happens in the original Graph. How can I resolve this Issue ?

Furthermore, the Code which is used to remove an edge is this

```
def remove_links(graph_dic,edge_number):
    count = 1
    V,U = '',' '
    for item in temp.items():
        for node in item[1].items():
            if count==edge_number:
                V = item[0]
                U = node[0]
            count+=1
    del graph_dic[V][U]
    return graph_dic
```

I don't want to have any changes in the original graph while also removing a specific edge that I want on the new copy. Furthermore, I'm running it on Jupyter Notebook...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but What i get is that change also happens in the original Graph

What you are doing is called: "Shallow copy". What you need to do is "Deep copy". You'd want to use: `copy.deepcopy` instead.